# PHP5 files giving output of html in apache2

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have followed following link to configure apache2 with php5.5.4:

http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

Everything got properly configured without any error. But now whenever I am trying to implement .php file, the output is looking like html file.

e.g.for following code

```
   <html>
   <head>
     <title>PHP Test</title>
     </head>
    <body>
    <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

The output in browser is:

Hello World

'; ?>

BUt in command line it is showing properly, i.e.

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>PHP Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>Hello World</p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Please guide in this aspect, since I have wasted so much time in this but in vain.
My system is Linux redhat x86_64.

Comment: You're missing the `AddType` or `SetHandler` declarations and/or you haven't restarted Apache. Also check error log to see whether mod_php encountered errors during load.

Comment: I did restart the apache with service httpd restart command. I did add whatever has mentioned in mentioned link also (http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php). If nything else is needed, please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

If Apache is not interpreting PHP, then you might not have configured right steps 7 and 8 of its link. Or not restarted apache after making the change in conf (step 9).